# linked list inside a linked list segmentation error

Tags: c, linked-list

```css
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct smallnode{
    char name[4];
    struct smallnode *next;
};
struct bignode {
  int no;
  struct smallnode *element;
  struct smallnode *ehead;
  struct bignode *next;
};
    struct bignode *classes;
    struct bignode *head;

void add_class(int no){
    struct bignode *newclass = malloc(sizeof(struct bignode));
    newclass->no=no;
    newclass->element=NULL;newclass->ehead=NULL;
    if(head==NULL){classes = newclass;head = classes;head->next=NULL;}
    else{
        head->next=newclass;
        head = head->next;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
}

void add_student(int noc,char* name){
    struct bignode *pointer;
    pointer = classes;
    int i;
    // get the desired class
    for(i=2;i<=noc;i++){
        pointer=pointer->next;
    }
    //add student to class
    struct smallnode *newstud;
    newstud = malloc(sizeof(struct smallnode));
    strcpy(newstud->name,name);
    if(pointer->element==NULL){
        pointer->element=newstud;
        pointer->ehead = pointer->element;
        pointer->ehead->next=NULL;
    }
    else{
        pointer->ehead->next=newstud;
        pointer->ehead = pointer->ehead->next;
        pointer->ehead->next=NULL;
    }
}

void resetdata(){
    struct bignode *classpointer;
    struct bignode *t;
    struct smallnode *studentpointer;
    struct smallnode *c;
    classpointer = classes;
    while(classpointer!=NULL){
        t=classpointer;
        studentpointer=classpointer->element;
        while(studentpointer!=NULL){
            c = studentpointer;
            studentpointer= studentpointer->next;
            free(c);
        }
        classpointer=classpointer->next;
        free(t);
    }
    classes = NULL;
    head = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp,*op;
    int sclasw=0;int adstud=0; int noc=1;int cp=0; char c; char sname[4]=""; int sc=0;
    int cases;

    classes = NULL;
    head = NULL;
    fp = stdin;
    op = stdout;
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("null");
    }
    cases =fgetc(fp)-'0';
    fgetc(fp);
    //reading
    int i;
for(i=1;i<=cases;i++){
    c = fgetc(fp);
    while(c!='\n'){
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if(c==':'){sclasw=1;}
        else if (c=='('&&sclasw==0){adstud=1;}
        else if (c=='('&&sclasw==1){}
        else if (c==')'&&sclasw==1){sclasw=0;add_class(noc);}
        else if (c==')'&&adstud==1){adstud=0;add_student(cp,sname);sc=0;}
        else if (sclasw==1&&c==','){
            add_class(noc);
            noc++;
        }
        else if (c==','&&adstud==1){
            add_student(cp,sname);
            sc=0;
        }
        else if (c==','&&sclasw==0&&adstud==0){
            cp++;sc=0;
        }
        else if(adstud==1){
            sname[sc]=c;
            sc++;
        }else if(sclasw==1){/*printf("-");*/}
    }
    //end reading
    //coloring algo
    struct bignode *classpointer;
    struct bignode *classpointer2;
    struct smallnode *studentpointer;
    struct smallnode *studentpointer2;
    int *color, totalcolor;
    color=malloc((noc+1)*sizeof(int));
    color[1]=1; totalcolor = 1;
    int col,oldcol;
    //breaker
    int b1=0,b2=0,b3=0;
    classpointer = classes->next;
    while(classpointer!=NULL){
        for(col=1;col<=totalcolor;){
            color[classpointer->no]=col;
            oldcol=col;
            studentpointer = classpointer->element;
            while (studentpointer!=NULL){//for the nth element
                classpointer2 = classes;
                while(classpointer2!=classpointer){//check the class
                    if (color[classpointer2->no]==col){
                        studentpointer2 = classpointer2->element;
                        while (studentpointer2!=NULL){// for an element
                            if(strcmp(studentpointer->name,studentpointer2->name)==0){//that has the same student as  the nth element
                                col++;//if theres the same student next color
                                color[classpointer->no]=col;
                                if(col>totalcolor){//if there is no next color create one
                                    totalcolor++;b1=1;
                                }
                                b2=1;
                                b3=1;
                                break;
                            }
                            studentpointer2 = studentpointer2->next;
                        }
                    }
                    classpointer2=classpointer2->next;
                    if(b3==1){b3=0;break;}
                }
                studentpointer = studentpointer->next;
                if(b2==1){b2=0;break;}
            }
            if (color[classpointer->no]==oldcol){break;}
            if(b1==1){b1=0;break;}
        }
        classpointer=classpointer->next;
    }
    //end algo
    fprintf(op,"Case %i: (",i);
    classpointer=classes;
    while(classpointer!=NULL){
        fprintf(op,"C%02i:%i",classpointer->no,color[classpointer->no]);
        classpointer=classpointer->next;
        if(classpointer!=NULL)fprintf(op,", ");
    }
    fprintf(op,")\n");
    resetdata();
    sclasw = 0; adstud = 0; noc=1;cp=0;sc = 0;
}
    return 0;
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(op);
}
```

//EDIT
Input:

```
1
Case 1: (C01,C02,C03,C04,C05,C06,C07,C08,C09,C10,C11),(RDA,ALB,NAC,EDF,BMG,VLJ,IVL,LGM,EGN,KSO,EST,VIV),(MCA,EDF,SLF,ADG,BCG,AAI,RRK,LGM,RLM,JGP,LRQ,WAR,KLS,DDY),(ABC,BBD,GCF,ADG,AKL,BCL,MIN,JGP,RSQ,DBU,IEY,RAW,ESZ),(ANA,JCA,CAB,NAC,GCF,GLH,VLJ,LLM,MAN,PEP,PQQ,ERR,SET,MAV,REW),(BBC,EDD,HSE,EST,ELG,ISH,JEI,EMJ,RRK,TPL,RER,EPS,AVU,CDW,ELY),(ALA,MCA,ABB,BCF,GLH,AKL,HGN,RON,JGP,ALQ,EPR,ABT,KEV,YEZ),(CDC,ISH,ABI,DHJ,ESM,FBM,RMN,PEP,VIR,JLS,LOT,MAV,TEX),(AAA,HLA,BBD,WRE,ECG,HLH,DHJ,RON,TSO,PQQ,MBT,REW,BAX,TRY,BDZ),(MCA,JCA,BCF,EGG,AAI,XTK,WIL,CSM,HLO,RSP,APR,RER,JET,DBU),(RDA,BBB,CLC,ECG,MNH,EMJ,JOK,ARM,NFM,EGN,RCN,RSP,LEQ,YIR,AVU),(ADB,WDB,BKC,CLC,SDE,UKF,BMG,HRH,BTK,LGM,QJP,EPS,KLS,BST,YNZ)
```

Output(in codeblocks which works just fine):

```
Case 1: (C01:1, C02:2, C03:1, C04:2, C05:3, C06:3, C07:1, C08:4, C09:4, C10:2, C11:4)
```

PS. I've already edited my source code such that there are no minor mistakes like insufficient memory for array.

This program does graph coloring by using 2 arrays. One for the classes and the other or student. The bigger linked list, which is the one for classes, has an element of a smaller linked list in each node;

Hackerrank's compiler says that it has a segmentation error, but it works fine when I run it in code blocks.
I've been stuck with this for days and I dont have any clue why this is happening. Please help me :(

Comment: `sname` isn't null-terminated. ? Also Show us sample of inputs.

Comment: `color=malloc(noc*sizeof(int));
    color[1]=1;` might occurs out-of-bounds error.

Comment: ok please wait sir, i still dont know how to paste inputs here

Comment: The two issues in your code have already been pointed out by Bluepixy: Don't allocate 4 chars with `malloc`; instead use `char sname[4] = "";` to create a buffer for three chars that is null-terminated in your special use case, where all strings are of length 3. You use a one-based numbering for the `no` field, which means that the highest number will go out of bounds. A quick fix to this is to allocate one more colour: `color=malloc((noc + 1)*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out these mistakes... I've already fixed it but hackerrank still says the same thing. I'm getting so tilted by this and have been trying different compilers online, some ran the program perfectly such as ideaone, and some had segmentation error like codeground.

Comment: Ok, It seems that hackerrank somehow didn't accept the '\n'. I was able to fix most of the problems now, the only problem is that when I reach 28+ cases, it starts to crash. I think its probably due to a stack overflow...